# File I/O in c++ and linux command line redirect

Tags: c++, linux, redirect, input

I've got a program that accepts a text file with a map on it, then finds the shortest path and outputs that to another file.

it needs to work like this

```
./pathFinder -arg < inputMap.txt > outputMap.txt
```

My question is, with this input, what would get filled into argv[] and argc (do the redirects count as arguments), and also should I use file streams or just cin/cout... or maybe something else. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried using cin and the program waits for input instead of using the txt file.

Comment: `cin` and `cout` are a "file streams".

Comment: Sorry, I meant ifstream and ofstream

Comment: @Max - if your program waits for input, then either you aren't invoking as you describe, or your program has a bug. Please reduce your program to the smallest version that still exhibits the problem, and post that here. For comparison, see [this program](http://ideone.com/KuTHp).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argc` will be 2, and `argv[1]` will point to `"-arg"`.

Redirects will simply appear on `stdin` and `stdout` (wrapped by `std::cin` and `std::cout`).

Comment: @quasiverse: No.  This is handled by the shell.

Comment: cin>>var hangs for keyboard input, is there a different way if you are expecting input from a file?

Comment: @Max: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  The shell literally streams in the content of the file instead of the characters you type at the console.

Comment: @Max If you redirect it and it *still* hangs then the file doesn't have the correct input or you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far...
When I run the program, it behaves the same way whether I include the redirects or not. (waits for input)

Comment: @Max: Do you mean that your program responds to what you type at the console?

Comment: Downvoter: Care to mention what you think is wrong with this answer?

Answer (score 2):

`argv` will contain `{"./pathFinder", "-arg"}`

Comment: @Kerrek: Thanks. I should have just used copy/paste.

Answer (score 0):

The redirect will not count as arguments.
Just use cin/cout will be fine.